# vim coloring for git

Tags: windows-7, vim, colors, conemu

I'm on Windows and my vim loads with a terrible colorscheme with vim. The message is blue on black (so I can't see what I'm typing). I need to change the colorscheme, but `:colorscheme slate` doesn't do anything.

```
:version
vim - vi improved 7.3 (2010 aug 15, compiled oct 27 2010 17:51:38)
ms-windows 32-bit console version
included patches: 1-46
compiled by bram@kibaale
big version without gui.  features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent +clientserver +clipboard
+cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments +conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape
+dialog_con +diff +digraphs -dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +gettext/dyn -hangul_input +iconv/dyn +insert_expand +jumplist
+keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname
 +mouse -mouseshape +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme -netbeans_intg -osfiletype +path_extra -perl
+persistent_undo -postscript +printer -profile -python -python3 +quickfix +reltime +rightleft -ruby
+scrollbind +signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl -tgetent -termresponse +textobjects +title -toolbar +user_commands
+vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows
+writebackup -xfontset -xim -xterm_save -xpm_w32
     system vimrc file: "$vim\vimrc"
         user vimrc file: "$home\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$vim\_vimrc"
            user exrc file: "$home\_exrc"
    2nd user exrc file: "$vim\_exrc"
compilation: cl -c /w3 /nologo  -i. -iproto -dhave_pathdef -dwin32   -dfeat_cscope       -dwinver=0x0400 -d_win32_winnt=0x0400  /fo.\objc/ /ox /gl -dndebug  /zl /mt -ddynamic_iconv -ddynamic_gettext -dfeat_big /fd.\objc/ /zi
linking: link /release /nologo /subsystem:console /ltcg:status oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib  comdlg32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib /machine:i386 /nodefaultlib  libcmt.lib   user32.lib
                        /pdb:vim.pdb -debug
```

My `$HOME\_vimrc` looks like

```
colorscheme slate
syn on
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
```

and my `$VIM\vimrc` is the stock vimrc that comes with the Windows Vim distribution.

**How do I change my console Vim colorscheme?** Especially for Git commits.

Comment: Read this [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/vim_dev/0H0qM1LJfuk/discussion) about 256-colors. As I said before, the work in progress, but solution is possible (in future builds thought).

Answer (score 1):

In your `$HOME\_vimrc`:

```
colorscheme slate
```

In the command line:

```
:colorscheme slate
```

If you have a `slate` colorscheme installed (which should be, it's installed by default) the above commands should work.

Did you change the color palette of your terminal emulator?

Comment: yes, it works in gVim. Not sure how to change the color palette of the terminal emulator though

Comment: If none of the default colorschemes is good enough, you can search [there](http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/html/index-html.html) for a colorscheme that supports 16 colors or on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=&script_type=color+scheme&order_by=creation_date&direction=descending&search=search)

Comment: In fact, there is ConEmu (I'm the author), which can deal with xterm 256 color (ansi esc-codes). If you are interested in it, you may ask question in 'conemu' tag or on project site.

Comment: @Maximus, I'm actually using ConEmu, it's now tagged